# In Excel 2010 many rows set to 0.00 pixels. How to set all rows to another height

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010, one of my co-workers set several rows to 0.00 row height. I need to set ALL rows to any other height but ZERO (0).

I have tried the following:

1. `UNHIDE`
2. `FORMAT>ROW HEIGHT`
3. `FORMAT>AUTO FIT ROW HEIGHT`
4. `COPY>PASTE SPECIAL>VALUES ONLY` (and all other PASTE options)
5. Selecting the entire sheet then manually resizing with the cursor,
   but this only works for one row at a time.

I have hundreds of these rows to fix, so that's no good. I know my way around Excel very well, but I'm at my wits end. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Having stated this in your question

> I know my way around Excel very well, but I'm at my wits end

I'm safely assuming that you would be able to run a simple macro in your spreadsheet and try to see if that would do the row re-sizing.

```
Sub Macro2()
Rows.Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Selection.RowHeight = 25
End Sub
```

If using VBA is an option, please try this. Feel free to change the row height from 25 to any desired height.

*Macro updated with `Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False` statement. See if this works for you.*

Comment: Dang it. It doesn't work. It does re-size the visible rows, but the "hidden" rows remain hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You will achieve your objective by manual row sorting. 
Make sure you select the entire sheet, upper left corner - click the intersection square.

After selecting all cells, manually adjust the height of one of the visible rows (doesn't matter which one). All rows will become of that height, including the hidden ones.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, no dice. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and figured it out in my case! (Excel 2013)

I had a table with hidden rows that I couldn't unhide at 1 time.

I selected the table, went to the table tools design tab, convert to range, now resize rows and voila!

Converted back to table. Had to resize some columns and reformat a little but all rows are visible now.

I hope this helps someone else out down the road!

Answer (score 0):

The rows you are trying to adjust might have a filter on it.  Highlight a surrounding cell or if you can get your cursor on one of the 0-height cells, check under the Sort & Filter option to see if a filter is for some reason turned on for these cells.  If it is, turn it off, and you should be able to adjust the cell heights as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in Office 365 Excel also, and found a simple solution.  Highlighting all rows and then attempting to set a row height, or selecting Autofit Row Height, does not resize rows with a height of zero pixels only when at least one selected row has a non-zero height.  If you first select all rows in the spreadsheet, and then manually set the height for every row to 0 pixels, you can then select all again, manually set the height to a non-zero value, and all rows will get resized.